# Creating invisible mode with code/pattern for running specific Android App

Tags: java, android, invisible

I'm building an Android App that her purpose to be secret, I dont want the icon will exist in the apps menu.
The idea is that that only the user that installed the app could use it with a private code he configured after installation.

1. Can I hide my app from the list and run it?
2. What are my options starting this app by entering kind of code/pattern for that use? and is it possibile to connect to the user lock\unlock system after screen looks and let him set a uniqe code that after entering it he could enter to the app mode.

I'll be happy getting some code or any kind of tutorials

Comment: This explain how to start it as a service when phone reboots, still didn't found any idea how to get in to the app using a secret code...

Answer (score 0):

I've seen other apps use a private dialling code/fake phone number to trigger opening a hidden app.

You can register a listener for [`NEW_OUTGOING_CALL`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL) and check the [`EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER) that is passed with it to cancel the call and open your app if the number matches your private code. Otherwise ignore and let the call go through as normal.

This obviously has permissions for that are needed that may look suspicious to potential users.

---

As for removing your app from the launcher as other's suggested and as described in the linked Question you need to remove the `<intent-filter>` from your `<activity>`

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```